# What are the advantages of a secretion controller in mvc?

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I want to show you one small programm. It is not a real program. I wrote it only to demonstrate.
Here is view:

```
public class View implements Observer {

private Model model;
private IController controller;

private JLabel firstNumber = new JLabel();
private JLabel secondNumber = new JLabel();
private JLabel resultLabel = new JLabel();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Model model = new Model();
            IController controller = new Controller();
            View view = new View();
            view.setModel(model);
            view.setController(controller);
            view.createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}

public void setModel(Model model) {
    this.model = model;
    model.addObserver(this);
}

public void setController(IController controller) {
    this.controller = controller;
}

public void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("mvc train");
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    frame.getContentPane().add(createMainPanel());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

private Component createMainPanel() {
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    mainPanel.add(firstNumber);
    mainPanel.add(secondNumber);
    mainPanel.add(resultLabel);
    JButton inc1 = new JButton("increment first");
    inc1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            controller.execute("inc1", model);
        }
    });
    JButton dec1 = new JButton("decrement first");
    dec1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            controller.execute("dec1", model);
        }
    });
    mainPanel.add(inc1);
    mainPanel.add(dec1);
    JButton inc2 = new JButton("increment second");
    inc2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            controller.execute("inc2", model);
        }
    });
    JButton dec2 = new JButton("decrement second");
    dec2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            controller.execute("dec2", model);
        }
    });
    mainPanel.add(inc2);
    mainPanel.add(dec2);
    return mainPanel;
}

@Override
public void update(Observable arg0, Object arg1) {
    firstNumber.setText("" + model.getA());
    secondNumber.setText("" + model.getB());
    resultLabel.setText("" + (model.getA() + model.getB()));
}

}
```

It looks like this:

[image]

Button "increment first" increments the left number. Button "increment second" increments the center number. Button "decrement first" decrements the left number. Button "decrement second" decrements the center number. The right number is the result of addition of the left and center numbers.
So, after two presses of a button "increment first" and one press button "increment second" we have this picture:

[image]

I store numbers in model. Here is my model:

```
public class Model extends Observable {

private int a;
private int b;

public void incrementA() {
    a++;
    setChanged();
    notifyObservers();
}

public void incrementB() {
    b++;
    setChanged();
    notifyObservers();
}

public void decrementA() {
    a--;
    setChanged();
    notifyObservers();
}

public void decrementB() {
    b--;
    setChanged();
    notifyObservers();
}

public int getA() {
    return a;
}

public int getB() {
    return b;
}

@Override
public void addObserver(Observer observer) {
    super.addObserver(observer);
    setChanged();
    notifyObservers();
}

}
```

And here is my controller:

```
public class Controller implements IController {

@Override
public void execute(String action, Model model) {
    switch (action) {
    case "inc1":
        model.incrementA();
        break;
    case "inc2":
        model.incrementB();
        break;
    case "dec1":
        model.decrementA();
        break;
    case "dec2":
        model.decrementB();
    }
}

}
```

1. What are the advantages of a secretion controller? We can to move code from switch in the controller into listeners. So, we would have four listeners. And now we have for branches in switch. I heard that controllers can be created for each element (in this case for each button). But in this case we can have four contollers. What are the advantages? Am I use the controller incorrectly?
2. In my example, all methods that are called in switch have no parameters. But some buttons could require methods with parameters, besides, with different number of parameters. What to do in such a situation?

Comment: Your example code seems needlessly indirect to me.  In a Java Swing application, you can have many controllers, each controlling one button.  Take a look at my [Kakurasu Using Java Swing](http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=795) article to see how I implement the model / view / controller pattern.